# Bootstrap form helper country state

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

> I need to add selected country and state while editing , I use

```
$("#countries_states1").val("IN").trigger("change");
```

> India gets selected but respective states in India is not loaded.I need to load Delhi city . I use

```
$('#states').bfhstates({country: IN, state: 'DE'});
```

> It shows error in that line

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).bfhstates is not a function
```

> What would do to select correct state .

Comment: you would need to post your code for someone to answer this

Comment: yes, i am struck on this .. can anybody give solution